# How to anchor brick vertically to concrete slab

Tags: concrete, brick, adhesive

Here's a concrete slab porch that was finished with paving bricks on top, and then matching pavers attached to the vertical front face with what appears to be some form of Liquid Nails.  The pavers sit on dirt.  The adhesive is failing to adhere them to the concrete.

What other materials or methods might durably hold these vertical pavers in place?

[image: Brick/paver not adhering to concrete]

Comment: I have seen a modern stylish building in Johannesburg, South Africa get a bolt with a washer through the centre of each sandstone tile after they started to fall off a few years after it was built.  The building is now covered with nuts.  (The roof is covered with solar collectors to mitigate load shedding) https://www.google.com/maps/@-26.1851651,28.0322933,3a,15y,248.93h,100.61t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s_R88q7RQPSWicXbyoEF86Q!2e0!7i13312!8i6656

Answer (score 3):

I've used this Loctite Premium for many types of concrete. It's waterproof and should work well with your pavers. Good luck

[image]

Comment: I'll give it a try.  To your knowledge is it substantially different from, or more effective than, Liquid Nails?

Comment: I have used this same product to glue down the top row of cap blocks on a retaining wall. Going on three years now and no sign of failure. This wall is wet a lot of the time considering the Pacific Northwest location.

Comment: @feetwet  I used Liquid Nails many years ago with  with unsatisfactory results.  They were not clear on what the product was good for.  They have added many newer products with good descriptions but I've never tried them after using the Loctite.. why mess with success..